# Blank page after multiple figures

Tags: blank-page

I am encountering a problem in my latex code, in fact my document contain many figures like this  :

```
\begin{center}
\begin{figure}[H]
\includegraphics[width=18cm]{notes1.pdf}
\end{figure}
\end{center}
```

In my document I repeat this syntax 14 times, the problem is that after 4 figures, I start having blank pages between each two figures.

Comment: Using `center` around a figure is wrong, using it inside almost as wrong. Use `\centering` inside the figure float. Which does not float, because you put a `[H]` on it.

Comment: For the given MWE, just drop the \begin{figure} and  \end{figure}.  It serves no function.